# How to detect end of IF loop when using sensorEventListener

Tags: android, loops, sensors, break

im getting linear acceleration from my phone and have a problem. 
I wanted to get i=i+1 if acceleration is higher than 10m/s but only add 1 ONCE not all the time readings are above 10 m/s. So thinking about getting the moment when values are getting down again below 10 and than adding +1 to i. Can Anyone help me?

For now im doing it like this but that works bad.

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    //odczytWyswX.setText(Float.toString(x));
    //odczytWyswY.setText(Float.toString(y));
    // odczytWyswZ.setText(Float.toString(z));

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
        gravSensorVals = lowPass(event.values.clone(), gravSensorVals);
        grav[0] = event.values[0];
        grav[1] = event.values[1];
        grav[2] = event.values[2];
    }

    odczytWyswZ.setText(Float.toString(grav[2]));
       wychwytywanieGornegoTapniecia();
}



 void wychwytywanieGornegoTapniecia(){
    if(grav[2]>10){   i++

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple boolean in your logic.

```
private boolean updateValue; // A field on the Class

    if (grav[2] > 10 && updateValue) {
        i++;
        updateValue = false;
    }

    if (grav[2] < 10) {
        updateValue = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bill that gaved me idea on how to do that! Changed it a little and worked like a charm!